# Pthread_setaffinity_np invalid argument

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, setthreadaffinitymask

I am trying to change the affinity of each thread inside the start routine.

Here's the code. In the below code, 't' is the argument passed through the pthread_create function.

```
    cpu_set_t mask;
    pthread_t c;

    a = *((int *)t);

    printf(" thread no. is %d \n",a);

    CPU_ZERO(&mask);

    a =a/2 + 1;

    CPU_SET(a,&mask);

    c=pthread_self();
    s=pthread_setaffinity_np(c,sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask);
    if (s!=0)
        handle_error_en(s,"pthread_setaffinity_np");
```

The thread affinity is not getting changed. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can replace the entire switch statement with `CPU_SET((a/2+1), &mask);`, by the way.

Comment: Perhaps better, to be sure it's evaluated only once, `a = a/2+1; CPU_SET(a, &mask);`.

Comment: Is there the slightest possibility that `a` is not in the range 0-15?

Comment: I changed the question. Thanks. This is how I am getting the value of 'a' - 
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) { 
        pthread_create(__,__,__,&i); 
    }

Comment: You're passing the same int pointer to all the threads, which all dereference it some time later, after the int has changed.

Comment: Also, maybe the function that created the threads returns before they read the int, and something else uses the same stack location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had misunderstood the bounds of the mask. That was where I was going wrong.